# How do I make Grails start a new log file on startup of the application?

Tags: grails, log4j

Which log4j appender should I use and how do I configure it?  I'm not too bothered about keeping old logs, so I don't care about truncating the existing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're logging to file, all log4j file appenders have an `append` property which you can set to false to always start fresh, or true to append to previous logs. eg:

```
appenders {
    rollingFile name: 'file', file: 'mySite.log', append: false
}
```